# Last iteration(?) of a NodeList causing Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code works just as expected but if I use `for (let line in hamburgerLines) {...}` I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle') at HTMLDivElement.addClass".

I used this alert function `alert("Here: " + line + " "+ hamburgerLines[line] + " " + hamburgerLines.length);`  to find out what's happening. It iterates normally three times and `hamburgerLines.length` does return `3` but then pops up another time putting out: "Here: entries function entries() { [native code] } 3" which I assume causes the error.

I already fixed this by changing it to `for (let line = 0; line < hamburgerLines.length; line++) {...}` but would like to know why it iterates once more through the for loop.

```js
let hamburgerButton = document.getElementById('hamburger-button');
hamburgerButton.addEventListener('click', addClass);

function addClass() {
  let hamburgerLines = document.querySelectorAll('.hamburger-line');
  for (let line in hamburgerLines) {
    hamburgerLines[line].classList.toggle('open-test');
  }
}
```

```css
header #hamburger-button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 30px;
  right: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* ---- Untoggled Hamburger Button ---- */

header .hamburger-line:nth-child(1) {
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

header .hamburger-line:nth-child(2) {
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

header .hamburger-line:nth-child(3) {
  width: 1px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}


/* ---- Toggled Hamburger Button ---- */

header .hamburger-line.open-test:nth-child(1) {
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #F00;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

header .hamburger-line.open-test:nth-child(2) {
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

header .hamburger-line.open-test:nth-child(3) {
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #F00;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="hamburger-button">
    <span class="hamburger-line"></span>
    <span class="hamburger-line"></span>
    <span class="hamburger-line"></span>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` object, check `NodeList` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

> Don't use for...in to enumerate the items in NodeLists, since they
> will also **enumerate its length and item properties and cause errors** if
> your script assumes it only has to deal with element objects. Also,
> for..in is not guaranteed to visit the properties in any particular
> order.
>
> for...of loops will loop over NodeList objects correctly:
>
> Recent browsers also support iterator methods (forEach()) as well as
> entries(), values(), and keys().

Answer (score 0):

You should use `for..of` loop instead of `for..in` and `toggle` the class as:

```
line.classList.toggle('open-test');
```

**`addClass` function**

```
function addClass() {
    let hamburgerLines = document.querySelectorAll('.hamburger-line');
    for (let line of hamburgerLines) {
        line.classList.toggle('open-test');
    }
}
```